# how can i fix "errors were encounterd while processing: mmodemanager whoopsie

Tags: gnome, software-installation, dpkg, android, desktop-environments

I am using an Ubuntu 13.10 image on my android and I cant seem to install the Ubuntu gnome desktop.

Device information:
 - Sony Xperia S (LT26I
 - Arm-V7
 - Snapdragon S3 1.83ghz
 - Adreno 220 GPU
 - four Armhf cpus

Ubuntu Information:
 - Linux 3.40 Kernel
 - version 13.10

```
envi@ubuntu:~$ adb shell
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
shell@android:/ $ su
root@android:/ # linux shell
Starting Shell as root@localhost
root@localhost:/# sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-shell is already the newesshell startingt version.
ubuntu-gnome-desktop is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/300 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: error processing modemmanager (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
Setting up whoopsie (0.2.24.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/whoopsie not found.
dpkg: error processing whoopsie (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 modemmanager
 whoopsie
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you tried to re-install as apt is asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall `modemmanager`, as it asks:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall modemmanager
```

Comment: Same error.  Error processing,  seems to only happen on 13.10,13.04. Not 12.10 or 12.04